Xamarin.Build.Download .net Maui Build Process Hanging at File Extraction GAppM-10.24.0.tgz
Description:
I am encountering an issue during the build process for an iOS application. The build seems to hang during the extraction of a specific file. The relevant portion of the build output is as follows:
Extracting C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\GAppM-10.24.0.tgz to C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\GAppM-10.24.0
The process gets stuck at this point and does not progress further. I have attempted to manually extract the file GAppM-10.24.0.tgz, and although this succeeds, the build still fails at the same extraction step.
On Android Build all works fine.
Could anyone provide insights or solutions to bypass this issue? Any tips on further diagnostics or configurations that might help resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Does it deploy on an iOS physical device and you use hot restart?

Could you please share the relevant code how you extract the specific file to help us reproduce the issue?

I solved the following problem as follows: I downloaded 7zip and set files with the extension .tar.tz to always open by default with 7zip. Then i downgraded the Plugin.Firebase Package to the version 2.0.14 and it works.

I had this issue also.  For me, the problem is that GAppM-10.24.0.tgz has files inside it with very long names.  These long names cannot extract to the  C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\ directory because it violates the MAX PATH length of 260 characters. (At least on Windows 10).  So it hangs trying to create a file it cannot create.
